# NSUrlSession taking ages, keep going even though app goes to background

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am calling a HTTP API that takes 80seconds to response. I am using NSURLSession and NSURLSessionDataTask to consume the API. There is a progress bar shown on the UI. How can I avoid the phone from going to sleep during this time and also keep the HTTP request running if the user puts my app into the background?

Comment: why you want to stop process in background? You can update UI while user open app from background.

Comment: I dont want to stop the process, I want it to keep running...